# Unable to use ADB in El capitan OSX

Tags: android, android-studio, osx-elcapitan

When I connect my Android device to my Mac running El Capitan, the charging light on the device comes on, but there is no USB debugging notification prompt. When I try using `adb`, no devices are found. I'm trying to build from Android Studio directly to the device.

When running Yosemite, everything worked fine.

Has anyone encountered this and what's the fix?

Comment: You could try revoking the usb debugging authorizations under developer options in settings

Comment: no luck, it don't even show a prompt if its charge only, MTP, PTP but its charging

Comment: Hmm. Maybe disable usb debugging, plug in it, reboot, then re-enable?  I really have no idea because my El Capitan works fine... All you did was upgrade from Yosemite and you aren't getting a USB debugging notification? I found a comment on Google that said using a different usb cord fixed that problem

Comment: I'm using the data cable that come with the LG G3... I will try to find some data cable and try

Comment: It works!!! just using other data cable, whats wrong with the LG one using sony data cable and it works...

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X 11.10.2 El Capitan uses "System Integrity Protection (SIP)" which blocks certain directories and executables, EVEN WITH ROOT USER (sudo). For me it blocks adb and fastboot.

You can google search how to turn SIP off by rebooting the Mac into the Recovery Partition, and then using terminal:

```
csrutil status


csrutil disable (then reboot)


csrutil enable (then reboot)
```

Once I turned SIP off then adb and fastboot worked again.